# client program not able to detect the file and send it to server in c programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets

i am developing a client server program using socket in c which is my unfamiliar programming language, my program will run on linux environment. I had recheck my establishment connection's program for both side which didnt have any error and all the required thing also being declare in a nice manner but when i run my server program, it show me waiting for client.Unfortunately, when i execute the client program, it only show me `usage: %s <filename> <IP address> [port number]`, the %s is use to display the file. There consist of one solution which i can think out but i also not sure it's the correct solution or not,i plan to use exec() system call to insert my exe file and file into it, because the exec() can use for execute a executable file directly. 
 What do i planning is correct or not ? 
 Here is my client program

*i use gcc to get an exe file first ,after that i issue ./exeFile to compile my exe file

```
/* getfile client */ 
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf and standard I/O */ 
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect, socklen_t */ 
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* sockaddr_in, inet_pton */ 
#include <string.h>     /* strlen */ 
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */ 
#include <fcntl.h>      /* O_WRONLY, O_CREAT */ 
#include <unistd.h>     /* close, write, read */ 

#define SRV_PORT 5105 
#define MAX_RECV_BUF 256 
#define MAX_SEND_BUF 256 

int recv_file(int ,char*); 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
   int sock_fd;  
   struct sockaddr_in  srv_addr;    
   if (argc < 3)  
   {    
      printf("usage: %s <filename> <IP address> [port number]\n", argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
   }        
     memset(&srv_addr, 0, sizeof(srv_addr)); /* zero-fill srv_addr structure*/   
      /* create a client socket */  
     sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);    
     srv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  /* internet address family */    
     /* convert command line argument to numeric IP */  
     if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[2], &(srv_addr.sin_addr)) < 1 ) 
      {    printf("Invalid IP address\n"); 
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
      }   
     /* if port number supplied, use it, otherwise use SRV_PORT */  
     srv_addr.sin_port = (argc > 3) ? htons(atoi(argv[3])) : htons(SRV_PORT);     
     if( connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &srv_addr, sizeof(srv_addr)) < 0 )  
     {    
       perror("connect error");    
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
     }   
       printf("connected to:%s:%d ..\n",argv[2],SRV_PORT);   
       recv_file(sock_fd, argv[1]); /* argv[1] = file name */   
        /* close socket*/   
         if(close(sock_fd) < 0)  
          {
             perror("socket close error");   
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
          }    
          return 0; 
} 
int recv_file(int sock, char* file_name) 
{ 
 char send_str [MAX_SEND_BUF]; /* message to be sent to server*/ 
  int f; /* file handle for receiving file*/  
  ssize_t sent_bytes, rcvd_bytes; 
  int recv_count,rcvd_file_size; /* count of recv() calls*/  
  char recv_str[MAX_RECV_BUF]; /* buffer to hold received data */  
  size_t send_strlen; /* length of transmitted string */    
  sprintf(send_str, "%s\n", file_name); /* add CR/LF (new line) */  
  send_strlen = strlen(send_str); /* length of message to be transmitted */   
  if( (sent_bytes = send(sock, file_name, send_strlen, 0)) < 0 ) 
  {   
   perror("send error");    
    return -1;  
  }  
   /* attempt to create file to save received data. 0644 = rw-r--r-- */  
   if ( (f = open(file_name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644)) < 0 )  
   {    
   perror("error creating file");    
   return -1;  
   }   
    recv_count = 0; /* number of recv() calls required to receive the file */  
    rcvd_file_size = 0; /* size of received file */    /* continue receiving until ? (data or close) */  
    while ( (rcvd_bytes = recv(sock, recv_str, MAX_RECV_BUF, 0)) > 0 )  
    {    
       recv_count++;    
       rcvd_file_size += rcvd_bytes;       
        if (write(f, recv_str, rcvd_bytes) < 0 )   
         {     
          perror("error writing to file");     
          return -1;    
         }  
   }  
   close(f); /* close file*/  
   printf("Client Received: %d bytes in %d recv(s)\n", rcvd_file_size, recv_count); 
   return rcvd_file_size; 
}
```

i can provide my server program if needed

Comment: How are you running your client-program? Through what command? Please add that in your question.

Comment: `./exeFile` doesn't compile the program (that's what gcc does), it just runs it. And according to your code, your program must be run with 2 or 3 arguments (the error message even tells you so!). How did you manage to write code (and a correct usage message) without understanding how it works?

Comment: can i know how to do it?